# Stylesheet in <link> tag will not render in Firefox or IE

Tags: html, css

I have an HTML document with a stylesheet referenced in a link tag. The character set is UTF-8 and is defined in the HTML and CSS files. In Chrome and Microsoft Edge, the CSS renders as it should, however in Firefox and IE it doesn't load it. There aren't any errors in the Console of Developer tools and no compilation errors in the IDE I am using.

I can go directly to the CSS file using the absolute file path in the URL bar and it will display the contents of the file, and it will render the HTML just fine. The CSS will render when I enclose it in style tags in the HTML file itself. However, I want to link tag it for organization.

I cannot find the solution anywhere even though many people have had this issue. I'm wondering if there is a known solution to this that could help me.

Here is the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>#</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="\css\core-test.css" media="screen">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <nav class="navbar">
            <a>#</a>
        </nav>
        <div class="table-box">
            <div class="table-body">
                <table id="main-table" class="table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>TIME</th>
                            <th>TICKER</th>
                            <th>CALL/PUT</th>
                            <th>EXPIRY</th>
                            <th>STRIKE</th>
                            <th>SPOT</th>
                            <th>PRICE</th>
                            <th>SIZE</th>
                            <th>TOTAL</th>
                            <th>OI</th>
                            <th>IV</th>
                            <th><button id="filterbtn" class="filterbtn fa fa-filter"></button></th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>00:12:34</td>
                            <td class="btc-color">BTC</td>
                            <td class="put-color">PUT</td>
                            <td>4/28</td>
                            <td>$7800</td>
                            <td>$7219</td>
                            <td>₿0.031</td>
                            <td>20</td>
                            <td class="put-color">₿62</td>
                            <td>1120</td>
                            <td>60.9%</td>
                            <td><button class="chartbtn fa fa-line-chart"></button></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>00:12:34</td>
                            <td class="btc-color">BTC</td>
                            <td class="put-color">PUT</td>
                            <td>4/28</td>
                            <td>$7800</td>
                            <td>$7219</td>
                            <td>₿0.031</td>
                            <td>20</td>
                            <td class="put-color">₿62</td>
                            <td>1120</td>
                            <td>60.9%</td>
                            <td><button class="chartbtn fa fa-line-chart"></button></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <div id="option-modal" class="option-modal">
                    <div id="option-modal-box" class="option-modal-box">
                        <span id="closebtn" class="closebtn">&times;</span>
                        <div id="option-modal-header" class="option-modal-header">
                            <a id="option-modal-header-title" class="btc-color option-modal-header-title">BITCOIN</a>
                        </div>
                        <div id="option-modal-body" class="option-modal-body">
                            <div id="chart-box" class="chart-box">
                                <div class="box-header">
                                    <a class="box-title">Chart</a>
                                </div>
                                <div style="background-color: gray;" class="box-body">
                                    <a>chart-box</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div id="orderbook-box" class="orderbook-box">
                                <div class="box-header">
                                    <a class="box-title">Orderbook</a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="box-body">
                                    <div class="orderbook-bid-body">
                                        <table id="orderbook-bid-table" class="orderbook-bid-table">
                                            <thead>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <th>TOTAL</th>
                                                    <th>SIZE</th>
                                                    <th>BID</th>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tbody>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td>1.0</td>
                                                        <td>1.0</td>
                                                        <td class="call-color">0.031</td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td>1.0</td>
                                                        <td>1.0</td>
                                                        <td class="call-color">0.031</td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </tbody>
                                            </thead>
                                        </table>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="orderbook-ask-body">
                                        <table class="orderbook-ask-table">
                                            <thead>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <th>ASK</th>
                                                    <th>SIZE</th>
                                                    <th>TOTAL</th>
                                                </tr>
                                            </thead>
                                            <tbody>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td class="put-color">0.032</td>
                                                    <td>1.0</td>
                                                    <td>1.0</td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td class="put-color">0.032</td>
                                                    <td>1.0</td>
                                                    <td>1.0</td>
                                                </tr>
                                        </table>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div id="stat-box" class="stat-box">
                                <div class="box-header">
                                    <a class="box-title">Greeks</a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="box-body">
                                    <table id="greek-table" class="option-modal-table">
                                        <thead>
                                            <tr>
                                                <th>MARK</th>
                                                <th>OI</th>
                                                <th>IV</th>
                                                <th>DELTA</th>
                                                <th>THETA</th>
                                                <th>VEGA</th>
                                                <th>GAMMA</th>
                                            </tr>
                                        </thead>
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td id="mark-greek">0.031</td>
                                                <td id="oi-greek">1120.0</td>
                                                <td id="iv-greek">60.9%</td>
                                                <td id="delta-greek">-0.2</td>
                                                <td id="thelta-greek">-9.0</td>
                                                <td id="vega-greek">1.23</td>
                                                <td id="gamma-greek">0.00012</td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div id="trade-box" class="trade-box">
                                <div class="box-header">
                                    <a class="box-title">Recent Trades</a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="box-body">
                                    <table id="trade-table" class="option-modal-table">
                                        <thead>
                                            <tr>
                                                <th>PRICE</th>
                                                <th>IV</th>
                                                <th>SIZE</th>
                                                <th>TIME</th>
                                            </tr>
                                        </thead>
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>0.032</td>
                                                <td>60.9%</td>
                                                <td>1</td>
                                                <td class="call-color">00:12:34</td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</body>

<script>
    var optionModal = document.getElementById("option-modal");
    var chartButton = document.getElementsByClassName("chartbtn");
    var closeButton = document.getElementById("closebtn");

    function openChart() {
        optionModal.style.display = "block";
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < chartButton.length; i++) {
        chartButton[i].addEventListener("click", openChart);
    }

    window.onclick = function(event) {
        if (event.target == optionModal) {
            optionModal.style.display = "none";
        }
    }

    closeButton.onclick = function(event) {
        if (event.target == closeButton) {
            optionModal.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
</script>

</html>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Overpass&display=swap);
@import url(https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css);
@charset "utf-8";

:root {
    --bg: #060c17;
    --item-bg: #0c1427;
    --main-font-color: white;
    --border: #262f43;
    --th-bg: black;
    --th-font: #7886a1;
    --btc: #ff8133;
    --eth: #106fb7;
    --call: #10b759;
    --put: #ff3366;
    --main-font: 'Overpass', sans-serif;
}

.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    position: absolute;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: var(--bg);
}

.navbar {
    position: fixed;
    padding: 20px;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    background: var(--item-bg);
    border-bottom: 1px solid var(--border);
}

.navbar a {
    color: var(--main-font-color);
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: var(--main-font);
}

.table-box {
    display: flex;
    border-radius: 0.25rem;
    margin-top: 75px;
    margin-bottom: 1px;
    height: 100%;
    width: 99%;
    background-color: var(--item-bg);
    border: 1px solid var(--border);
    overflow: hidden;
}

.filterbtn {
    color: var(--th-font);
    background-color: var(--th-bg);
    font-size: 14px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.table-body {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 40px;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    border-top: 1px solid var(--border);
}

.table {
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: var(--main-font);
}

.table thead {
    color: var(--th-font);
}

.table tbody {
    color: var(--main-font-color);
}

.table thead th {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    background-color: var(--th-bg);
}

.chartbtn {
    font-size: 14px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 0.25rem;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: var(--th-font);
    background-color: var(--th-bg);
}

.table thead th,
.table tbody td {
    text-align: left;
    padding: 10px 10px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid var(--border);
}

.table tbody tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: var(--bg);
}

.btc-color {
    color: var(--btc);
}

.eth-color {
    color: var(--eth);
}

.call-color {
    color: var(--call);
}

.put-color {
    color: var(--put);
}

.option-modal {
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    padding-top: 20px;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

.option-modal-box {
    display: flex;
    margin: auto;
    height: 95%;
    width: 90%;
    background-color: var(--item-bg);
    border: 1px solid var(--border);
    border-radius: 0.25rem;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.closebtn {
    padding-top: 0.5%;
    right: 6%;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: var(--main-font);
    position: fixed;
    color: var(--main-font-color);
}

.option-modal-header {
    position: fixed;
    margin: 5px;
}

.option-modal-header-title {
    position: sticky;
    font-family: var(--main-font);
    font-size: 20px;
}

.option-modal-body {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin-top: 40px;
    height: 90%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: var(--item-bg);
    overflow: auto;
}

.option-modal-body div {
    min-width: 50%;
}

.orderbook-bid-body {
    display: inline-table;
}

.orderbook-bid-table {
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: var(--main-font);
}

.orderbook-bid-table thead {
    color: var(--th-font);
}

.orderbook-bid-table tbody {
    color: var(--main-font-color);
}

.orderbook-bid-table thead th {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    background-color: var(--th-bg);
}

.orderbook-bid-table thead th,
.orderbook-bid-table tbody td {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px 0px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid var(--border);
    border-right: 1px solid var(--border);
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

.orderbook-bid-table tbody tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: var(--bg);
}

.orderbook-ask-body {
    float: right;
}

.orderbook-ask-table {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: var(--main-font);
}

.orderbook-ask-table thead {
    color: var(--th-font);
}

.orderbook-ask-table tbody {
    color: var(--main-font-color);
}

.orderbook-ask-table thead th {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    background-color: var(--th-bg);
}

.orderbook-ask-table thead th,
.orderbook-ask-table tbody td {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px 0px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid var(--border);
    border-right: 1px solid var(--border);
    border-left: 1px solid var(--border);
}

.orderbook-ask-table tbody tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: var(--bg);
}

.option-modal-table {
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: var(--main-font);
}

.option-modal-table thead {
    color: var(--th-font);
}

.option-modal-table tbody {
    color: var(--main-font-color);
}

.option-modal-table thead th {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    background-color: var(--th-bg);
}

.option-modal-table thead th,
.option-modal-table tbody td {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px 0px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid var(--border);
}

.option-modal-table tbody tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: var(--bg);
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
    .chart-box {
        width: 100%;
    }
    .orderbook-box {
        width: 100%;
    }
    .stat-box {
        order: 4;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .trade-box {
        width: 100%;
        order: 3;
    }
}

.chart-box {
    height: 50%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.orderbook-box {
    height: 50%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.stat-box {
    height: 49%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.trade-box {
    height: 49%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.box-header {
    height: 6%;
    padding: 5px;
}

.box-title {
    color: var(--main-font-color);
    font-family: var(--main-font);
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: auto;
}

.box-body {
    border: 1px solid var(--border);
    height: 89%;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using forward slashes `/` instead of the backslashes?

Comment: `href="\css\core-test.css"` looks suspicious. What do you see when you open the dev tools. Do you get an error? Also, check the network tab. Try to look for signs that the file wasn't fetched.

Comment: @JeffBerlin I have tried all forward slashes and it still doesn't work.

Comment: @TheFool No errors anywhere in Developer Tools

Comment: Show your network tab. Open the network tab in dev tools and shift refresh the page. Look for a filename in red meaning it wasn't fetched.

Comment: @TheFool The HTML and CSS are local files and are not being requested from a remote IP. Still I checked the Network tab and there aren't any errors indicating the CSS wasn't fetched.

Comment: Files from the local system are also shown in the network tab. They are essentially fetched the same way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could the backslashes be the problem?

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/core-test.css" media="screen">
```

Try changing them to forward slashes.

Comment: I have tried all forward slashes and still doesn't work.

Comment: If you're just opening the HTML-file directly in your browser and the both that file and the CSS folder are located in the same directory, you should remove the first slash. Otherwise, the path will be interpreted as absolute.

Comment: I abbreviated the file path for simplicity purposes so the file path begins with C:\ and ends in \css\core-test.css. Both forward and backward slashes do not work.

Comment: If they are local, try relative URL's. You can just write 'css/core-test.css' as path to the CSS-file, if the CSS-folder is within the same folder as the HTML file.

Comment: I changed the href to css\core-test.css and that did the trick. Thank you Lenny.